# Convert String to URL for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, gmaps.js

I am working on a simple project trying to figure out different parts of the GMaps.js API for HTML5.

Currently I have a map that gets populated with a list of locations, and I have Info Windows set up for each location which shows the location's name, address, and phone number.

Currently I am trying to set it up so that the Info Window also contains a direct link to a Google Maps page for the specific location.  I am trying to accomplish this by parsing the string that contains the name of the place and adding it to the end of `https://www.google.maps.com/maps/place/<location name>`

Right now my 'parsing' is honestly just replacing spaces with `+` signs.  So a name like `Eastwood Arena` gets turned into `Eastwood+Arena` for the URL.  My problem, comes when I encounter names that have special characters like &, (, or ).  In these cases the Google Maps page is loading, but it just loads to a random location without loading the actual place I am looking for.

What is the proper way to parse a string for the use I am trying to set up?  I can't seem to find a good answer to this question.  In case the parsing isn't my problem, this is my javascript/jquery code:

```
var map;
function generateMarker(markerInfo) {
    addressURL = markerInfo["address"].split(' ').join('+');
    addressURL += ',+'+markerInfo["city"].split(' ').join('+');
    placeURL = markerInfo["name"].split(' ').join('+');
    googleURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/"+placeURL;
    xmlURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="+addressURL;
    infoWindowString = '<p>'+markerInfo["name"]+
                       '</br>'+markerInfo["address"]+
                       '</br>'+markerInfo["city"]+
                       '  '+markerInfo["phone"]+
                       '</br>'+'<a href="'+googleURL+'">Google Maps</a>'+
                       '  '+'<a href="'+xmlURL+'">Lat/Long XML</a></p>';
    map.addMarker({ 
            lat: markerInfo["latitude"],
            lng: markerInfo["longtitude"],
            infoWindow: {
                content: infoWindowString                                                       
            }
        });
    console.log(infoWindowString);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    latitude =  43.243603 ;
    longitude = -79.889075;
    map = new GMaps({div: '#map',lat: latitude,lng: longitude });
    for (var i = 0; i < listRecs.length; i++) {
        generateMarker(listRecs[i]);
    }
    map.fitZoom();
});
```

Comment: Just remove these `split` and `join` and encode your strings properly: `googleURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + encodeURIComponent(placeURL);`

Comment: Doing that goes to the google maps page with the location's name in the search box, but doesn't actually load the location data

Comment: @blex Actually, it makes my problem weirder.  Some of the locations I was having trouble with before, load properly, while some other that were working, don't anymore.  :\

Comment: Could you give some examples ? I could not find ones that don’t work

Comment: @blex Sure, here's one.  `Carlisle Community Centre & Arena` is the location name I have, and should link to [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Carlisle+Community+Centre/@43.3966871,-79.9835158,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x882b7c48d64d81a7:0xef3aae14b950517d!8m2!3d43.3966832!4d-79.9813271)

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but I think this is because the place is unknown to Google with that exact name (it only knows it without the `& Arena` part). Doing a search, like this, seems to work: `"https://maps.google.com/?q=" + encodeURIComponent('Carlisle Community Centre & Arena')`

Comment: @blex Thank you.  Changing the URL to the request URL instead of the direct link fixed my problem.  If you want to throw that up as an answer I'll throw the rep at you and mark it as such :)

Comment: Have a look at [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) which is currently recommended by Google way to generate valid cross-platform links.